# Checking/Unchecking TMenuItem without closing the TPopupMenu

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select a Menu Item without closing the Menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983217/how-to-select-a-menu-item-without-closing-the-menu)

When the popup menu is showing I need to check/uncheck items but I dont want the popup menu to close and reopen.
It causes an annoying flicker.

Here is my code so far:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu;
    N11: TMenuItem;
    N21: TMenuItem;
    N31: TMenuItem;
    procedure PopupMenu1Popup(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    PopupPt: TPoint;
    procedure OptionClick(Sender: TObject);
  public
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Self.PopupMenu := PopupMenu1;
  PopupMenu1.OnPopup := PopupMenu1Popup;
  N11.OnClick := OptionClick;
  N21.OnClick := OptionClick;
  N31.OnClick := OptionClick;
end;

procedure TForm1.OptionClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PopupMenu1.Tag := 1;
  try
    (Sender as TMenuItem).Checked := not (Sender as TMenuItem).Checked;
    PopupMenu1.Popup(PopupPt.x, PopupPt.y);
  finally
    PopupMenu1.Tag := 0;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.PopupMenu1Popup(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if PopupMenu1.Tag = 0 then
    PopupPt := Mouse.CursorPos;
end;
```

My question, can this be done better?

---

EDIT 1: There is a small problem with the *duplicate* accepted answer [How to select a Menu Item without closing the Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5986290/1140885):

If I set `Item.Checked := not Item.Checked` right after `Item.Click;` (`MenuSelectID` method) - The Item is **not invalidated**, and the check is not drawn until I leave the Item area and Enter back to it... 
I have also tried: `CheckMenuItem(Menu.Handle, ItemID, MF_BYCOMMAND or MF_CHECKED);` - Same effect.

So, I'm back to ground zero, becouse my main goal is to Check/Uncheck menu items. same as with [status bar context menu](http://privat.rejbrand.se/officestatuscontext.png) in Microsoft Office (2010 at least):

---

EDIT 2: Adding `InvalidateRect(FPopupWindowHandle, nil, False);` right after setting `Checked` fixed the invalidation problem.

Comment: See [How to select a Menu Item without closing the Menu?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5983217/576719). The example shows how to do this with a `TPopupMenu`.

Comment: @LURD, Thanks. my question is in fact exact duplicate.

Comment: "InvalidateRect(FPopupWindowHandle, nil, False);" do you know how to make that work with VCL styles on?