# How to change TPopupMenu and TMainMenu Behaive to be fully RightToLeft in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo Update 1?

Tags: delphi, menu, right-to-left, popupmenu

I want to make two new menu objects like TPopupMenu and MainMenu in Delphi Xe10 but both of them must be kind of right to left without using BidiMode option.
Actually my application can not be RightToLeft at all I need to change appearance of the Painted panels of menus. I want to open menu items left of mouse pointer and submenus must appear left of first level. I researched on the internet and found a registry key named " MenuDropAlignment " that must set to zero for RightToleft . but its not working properly. second levels appear on the right-hand of first level panel of menu.please consider to this two pictures. the Right-handed is the purpose in win XP and Win7 and above.

**Could any one help me please to make this menu component?**

[image: Main menu]
[image: Context menu]

Comment: The OS will decide where submenus open - user choice at tablet options (as long as screen space is enough to display the submenu). Otherwise you have to device your own menu system, from scratch.

Comment: .. perhaps not from scratch, by emulating submenus. Add a dummy item, manually launch a popup in its onclick - maybe... like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28055261). The popup may close the main though...

Comment: The OS also positions menus so they will be visible - move a window mostly off the screen to the right and open it's system menu for example.

Comment: Thank you for your attention @sertac Akyuz...I know ! and I tried to take the pattern from Tmenu class and I need some help to change it correctly.

Comment: .. or employ some hook that would grab each and every menu window, and position it yourself. Like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16873245).

Comment: Same place the screenshot came from has other suggestions: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/68038-set-menus-open-aligned-left-right-windows-10-a.html

Comment: @Brian , that Solution works for tablets and just in win10.

Comment: Would be useful perhaps to know what delphi version you use. No such thing as XE10.

Comment: I'm working with Embarcadero Delphi 10.2 Tokyo + Update 1

Comment: Please don't write that as a comment. Edit the question to correct the text, and add the appropriate delphi version tag.