# Embed Menu/PopupMenu or TListItems on a form

Tags: delphi

Is there any way to embed a TPopupMenu directly on a form, as if it was a panel always open? or maybe just the TMenuItems.

Comment: No, it's not possible. Of course there are many ways to create a good-looking and user-friendly menu, but embedding a constantly open context menu isn't possible. Perhaps a simple `TToolBar` will work for you?

Comment: Or maybe a way to keep the menu open after you click on an item

Comment: *That* is possible. But it will close if your app loses focus or if you click somewhere outside the menu.

Comment: I thought of embedding it to a (~popup) form as a way to select a few options/filters, a simple menu is very handy for that but not if it closes after a click or loses focus too easily. It has auto-checkmarks, good looking ~hot-tracking, easy separators and icons..

Comment: Menus are expected to disappear once an item has been clicked. Consider showing/hiding tool windows.

Comment: Nothing I tried looks nearly as good and practical as a PopupMenu :( I came across this very nice solution (2nd answer) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983217/how-to-select-a-menu-item-without-closing-the-menu the only problem is with VCL styles, an item with Auto-check does not repaint to show the checkmark until you hover away from it onto another item.

Comment: Then you might want to create a custom control. Also, if you want to make a robust and bug-free application, you might want to abandon VCL styles altogether...

Comment: It's just a hobby/free app.

Comment: @hikari please link answers then, not questions - I assume https://stackoverflow.com/a/25834877/4299358

Comment: Yeah that one, it just has that VCL styles issue.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand "*A menu ... isn't a window*" - yes it is. It's just not a window that you have direct access to, but its HWND can be obtained with some work. Its class name is "#32768"

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, it makes sense that it is implemented as a window under the hood. (By the way: Do you know if this has always been the case?) I've removed my incorrect comment. Still, the practical consequences are not changed: you don't want to try to make a Win32 menu into a stationary control on a form.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: This got me wondering: surely the mouse cursor isn't a window, or is it?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand that, I don't know

Comment: @Andreas - [It isn't](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/pointer-control). Note the "Drv" prefix for GDI functions mentioned in the link (when it's needed to fallback on GDI) which specifies them as device driver interface functions.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: Thanks for confirming that. I'd been very surprised if that was a window too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible to embed a menu on a form. The reason is partly that a menu isn't an ordinary window that you can easily manipulate.

So you need to find a different solution. And there are many options you can chose from:

1. Using a `TToolBar`:

   [image: A screen recording of a form with two vertical toolbar (in different visual styles) with auto-check buttons.]

   It doesn't look particularly modern and out of the box you don't get much control over the appearance, though. Also, I don't know exactly how robust this solution is. I stopped using toolbars many years ago.
2. Using a `TCheckListBox`:

   [image: Screenshot of a form with a check list box.]

   In this case, I'd recommend you to create a subclass `TCheckListBoxEx` which toggles an item if you double-click its caption.
3. Creating a custom control:

   This is what I'd do if it is about a central GUI in an important application, because this way you get full control over the appearance and behaviour and can make it really robust. I have done a modern such menu at work, but currently I am at home so I cannot show you it. Here, however, is a menu I made more than ten years ago for a hobby project:

   [image: Screen recording of a custom-control-based solution with auto-toggling items.]
4. If you don't need the menu to be attached to the form like a control, but only need it not to close when you select an item in it, there are (hacky) ways to achieve that. But that is a different Q.

Comment: Had a look at TToolbar, it's terrible tbh

Comment: @hikari: The `TToolBar` is mainly supposed to be used for the classic kind of toolbars that you find in for instance Explorer or WordPad in Windows 95. For that intended purpose, it is brilliant (albeit slightly dated visually).

Comment: The benefit of the toolbar in this case is that it can be driven by actions (e.g. in a `TActionList`), just like menu items can (should) be.